# How can I make two threads respond only to each other when there are more than two threads running - Java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I'm doing a project where I need to create a java server and some clients, so that the clients can play tic-tac-toe over the server.The clients and the server would be in the same network, so there wouldn't be any problems with IPs, they would always be the same. Now for the problem, there would only be two players playing together one match, but there would be multiple matches running so the server should handle that. The problem I ran into was that I am using threads on the server to exchange moves between the clients, and I don't know how to make one thread communicate only to one other thread, without notifying or interacting with the other threads that it's not currently playing against.
Is there any way to isolate two threads from other threads?
I can't upload any code because I don't even know where to start.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

since you are in private network and using sockets then you can use the address of each client for the identification more over you can assign one object to two clients as synchronized object so that inter thread communication could be done.

Answer (score 0):

this problem is similar to chat app. try to look at any xmpp based application server (openfire)

Answer (score 0):

If your whole game takes place on one socket, you don't have a problem. When your server socket accepts, create a thread, and let that thread handle the socket. No other thread even has that socket in scope.

If you want each game move to happen on a separate socket connection, while a longer-lived thread maintains game state, it's more complicated.

---

Possibly the simplest solution would be for each server thread to have its own server socket, using a dynamically assigned port. The server would have a well-known port on which a new session would be negotiated:

```
  client                             server

  connect (well known port) -------> accept (well known port)
  request new game          -------> create new server socket (dynamic port)
                                     launch thread to listen on dynamic port
  receive dynamic port num  <------- respond with dynamic port num
  connect (dynamic port)    -------> (in thread) accept, handle game
  play game on this socket  -------> ...
```

There are some details to work out, like whether to keep the first socket open, or to close it after the negotiation.

This is a reasonably well established pattern (it's similar to FTP, for example). Firewalls can be problematic with protocols that work in this sort of way.

---

Another option is to keep sending all your requests to the same port, handled by a single `ServerSocket`, and dispatch requests to the appropriate thread. To do that you would need a session ID, which would be part of each request.

One way to do this is to create a queue for each game thread. Each thread reads commands off its queue. The dispatcher puts requests on the appropriate queue.

When you create a new game thread:

```
  // in the dispatcher
  Queue<Request> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
  String sessionId = generateSessionId(); // UUID, whatever
  gamequeues.put(sessionid, queue); // gameQueues is a Map<String,Queue<Request>>
  Game game = new Game(queue, sessionId);
  new Thread(game).start();
```

When you received a request for a game event:

```
  // also in the dispatcher
  String sessionId = request.getSessionId(); // HTTP header, something from payload, whatever
  queue.add(request);

  // In the thread
  while(game.isActive()) {
      Request request = queue.take();
      handle(request);
  }
```

---

Although I've shown a simple implementation using a Queue class from the JDK, queue implementations such as the various JMS implementations (e.g. ActiveMQ), Kafka, Redis, give you more powerful abstractions to work with. For example, all of these allow you to define a single queue, but for a consumer to take only messages matching a header (e.g. session id).

---

In all of these examples, if security is a concern, you need to defend against session key stealing.

Answer (score 0):

Two thread communicate each other on the common lock you are using.If two thread need to communicate each other then use a common lock between them.